# Trouble with deploying a dockerized Angular application through Jenkins

Tags: angular, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, dockerfile

I set up an environment in which I want to deploy an angular application. To get some experience with docker and jenkins, I tried utilizing both. Currently, I'm able to deploy the angular application in a docker container.

What I can't get to work is deploying this container through Jenkins. 
What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. When Jenkins detects changes in the git repo, build a new docker container.
2. Shutdown the old container (and only that one).
3. Deploy the new container.

These are the build commands I have currently set in jenkins:

```
docker build -t angular-docker .
docker run -d -p 80:80 angular-docker
```

Now, when these commands are executed, I get an "Port is already in use" error - which makes sense, since the old container has been running on the port. What I don't understand is how I would tell jenkins to "overwrite" the old container by shutting it down and deploying the new one.

I'd appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction, or tell me, that my approach is completely wrong. I'm pretty new to this, so that might very well be the case. Thanks!
I'm struggling to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all is a good practice to name your containers:

```
docker build -t angular-docker .
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name angular-app angular-docker
```

Then you should first run this before trying to install the new version

```
docker rm -f angular-app
```

Do this on a clean situation otherwise you will have the same problem since the old container is not named.

Hopefully this fixes it for you.